# What is the use of enclosing multiple commands in parenthesis in a Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

There are several ways to run multiple commands at one go.  One way is by separating each command with semicolon:

```
ls;who;banner Hi
```

Another way is by enclosing multiple commands in parenthesis.

```
(cd mydir;pwd)
```

What will happen by enclosing them in parenthesis?

Comment: Note that `$(cd mydir; pwd)` has a different meaning from `(cd mydir; pwd)`. I've updated the question to reflect what I'm tolerably certain you intended to mean/write (but you can change it if I'm wrong).  Also, as a point of pedantry, the `ls;who;banner Hi` runs three commands sequentially, just as if you'd typed `ls` then `who` then `banner Hi`.  To run them all at once, you'd need `ls&who&banner Hi` (preferably with spaces around the ampersands).  You can also write `{ ls; who; banner Hi; } >somefile` to do I/O redirection on all the commands at once. The third semicolon is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parentheses create a subshell. A subshell is a copy of them current shell, which means that state changes such as changing the working directory with `cd` or setting shell variables or exporting environment variables don't affect the original shell.

In the case here, the `cd` command changes the working directory, and `pwd` shows this. When the prompt returns you will still be in the same directory where you were before because `cd` changed the directory only in the subshell.

Comment: Can you please tell me when we have to enclose multiple commands in paranthesis and when to separate multiple commands with semicolon? @Joni

Comment: Use parenthesis when you want a subshell.

Comment: hmm..,but please let me know what is the use of subshell? @Joni